# Microsoft Azure Web App Publish from BitBucket stopped working

Tags: azure, bitbucket

When I try to deploy from my Bitbucket repo from an azure web app, I get the following error

```
Failed to set up deployment source for web app XXXXXXXXX, using Bitbucket. Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: Bitbucket AddSSHKey: (404) NotFound.
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.BitbucketV2Proxy.<AddSSHKey>d__57.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.BitbucketV2SiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext().
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error mentions being unable to find an ssh key. Maybe it's due to this? Maybe this is an extra layer of security which won't let App Service connect to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently today bit bucket have, experiment some problems with the oauth services, I check this using a mirrow in github and try to deploy in azure and work. 
The normal solution to this it is change the right permission for the user in bitbucket.

Comment: Yep.  Looks like it was a temporary problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by a security change or ownership of a repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-authorizations/ and revoke access to azure then it worked when it was re-added